# Do you need 6 months validity on passport to return to USA from Canada on E3 visa?

Tags: usa

i am wondering if there is any requirement for minimum time left on a passport when re-entering the united states on an e3 visa.  I have heard that you must have a minimum of 6 months remaining on a passport to enter but i cannot find this requirement documented in any searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a six month requirement in the US, but [many countries, including Australia, are exempt from the requirement](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Six%20Month%20Club%20Update_0.pdf).

On an E-3 you should be fine as long as the passport is valid when you reenter.

Comment: Thanks, I think i will try to book my interview while in Vancouver so i don't have to worry about this in future re-entries

Comment: It doesn't only apply to visitors. It applies to all nonimmigrant visa entries, including E-3.

Comment: An E-3 is okay since all of those are Australians. I committed a thinking error on the other bit, however. It does indeed apply to all nonimmigrants on entry, it is only that for those living in the US renewing the passport and extending the stay granted at the PoE is usually convenient enough to not to practically limit your stay after that. I fixed it.